# Nginx site configuration disabling 301 rewrite for another site

Tags: redirect, nginx, http-status-code-301

I currently have two enabled site configurations in nginx, let us call them `old-site.example` and `new-site.example`. There is no other site configuration active.

`old-site.example` should 301-redirect to `new-site.example`. This currently works well as long as the `old-site.example` configuration is alone. After adding the `new-site.example` configuration file, it does not redirect anymore.

`oldsite.conf`:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name *.old-site.example;
        rewrite_log on;
        location / {
                return 301 http://www.new-site.example$request_uri;
        }

}
```

`newsite.conf`:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.new-site.example;

charset utf-8;

    location / {
        #forward to application server
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

other configuration details:

- JBoss AS7 as application server running behind Nginx 1.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a DNS related error, sorry everyone.

Background: The ISP of the client managed to "smart redirect" the domain instead of using DNS. They basically scraped the new site on their servers and returned it via the old domain. I'm speechless.

If you ever have a problem like this, check DNS resolution before second-guessing your config.

Comment: Just adding another note, since I use firefox i noticed something that's kind of related, firefox sometimes caches the 301 responses, so even if you change the settings firefox doesn't know the new settings, so you should clear the cache and try again, sometimes this is the issue